# Get the JSON value

Tags: angularjs, json

JSON

```
{"discountPriceValues":[[{"Price":"3.0"},{"Scode":"S0375102"}],[{"Price":"2.0"},{"Scode":"s0779548"}]],"isEmployeeOJ":"Y"}
```

APP.JS

```
var test = $http.get("data/test.json").then(function (response5) {
  $scope.testing = response5.data;
  return response5;
});
test.then(function(testing){
    $scope.testing = testing.data.discountPriceValues;
    //console.log($scope.testing);
});
```

How to access the isEmployeeOJ value. I tried with the below code, but I'm getting undefined in console.

```
console.log($scope.testing.isEmployeeOJ);
```

Comment: depends on **where** you tried your console.log, because `$http` callback is **asynchronous**. If you are calling anything outside of `.then()`, it will be called before your AJAX response and therefore stay undeclared as _undefined_. Put your console.log inside `.then()`

Answer (score 0):

Need to parse it using angular.fromJson || JSON.parse()

After that it is just a JSON object. For eg:

```
console.log(JSON.parse($scope.testing.isEmployeeOJ));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this.test = {"discountPriceValues":[[{"Price":"3.0"},{"Scode":"S0375102"}],[{"Price":"2.0"},{"Scode":"s0779548"}]],"isEmployeeOJ":"Y"}

alert(this.test.isEmployeeOJ)
```

Or in HTML :

```
{{test.isEmployeeOJ}}
```

This code works :)

Comment: in his example `test` is a Promise, not a variable. You might be thinking of using `testing.data.isEmployeeOJ`

Comment: Data is not needed... data is for response5, but it's strange... he do $scope.testing = response5.data; but return response5

Comment: he returns `return response5;` not `return response5.data;` in his first promise, so he actually needs to extract `data` from `testing` first, before accessing JSON

Answer (score -2):

simply you can do this way

```
obj = testing = {"discountPriceValues":[[{"Price":"3.0"},{"Scode":"S0375102"}],[{"Price":"2.0"},{"Scode":"s0779548"}]],"isEmployeeOJ":"Y"}
{discountPriceValues: Array(2), isEmployeeOJ: "Y"}

console.log(obj.isEmployeeOJ)
```